# Web service to get diff between two files

Tags: web-services, rest, web, diff, git-diff

I am looking for a web service which provides diff between two files in html format ( with red, green coloring if possible). Is there any such service available?

Thanks,
Kailas

Answer (score 0):

general - https://www.diffchecker.com/

json - tlrobinson.net/projects/javascript-fun/jsondiff/

Comment: These are online tools to get diff between files. Whereas I am looking for Web Service apis (Rest/Soap) to be called from my application to get file diffs.

Comment: why does it have to be a web service? where do you intend to use the result? if it's client - than you have the solution, if server - just call diff or any other console tool. you need to provide more context.